# How to use std::copy output with std::distance for a C-style array type

Tags: c++

How can I store the OutputIterator returned from `std::copy` to be used as parameter for a later `std::distance` call?

I cannot use auto from C++11 and I need to use c-style arrays.

That's kind of what I'm trying to do:

```
unsigned char data[MAX_DATA_LEN];
unsigned char x[MAX_X_LEN], y[MAX_Y_LEN];

// I cannot use auto here
auto out =
  std::copy ( x,
              x + runtime_x_len ,
              std::copy ( y,
                          y + runtime_y_len ,
                          data ) );

size_t data_size = std::distance ( data , out );
```

Comment: A std::copy to the result of a std::copy appears useless and wrong

Comment: @RyanHaining: Please do not submit answers in the comments section. This is a Q&A, not a Q&C. Thanks.

Comment: @DieterLücking: Of course, that _could_ simply be a lack of imagination on your part...

Comment: @DieterLücking, we can use chained calls this way. It is not wrong!

Comment: @dieter: Why? It seems a perfectly sensible way to concatenate.

Comment: std::copy(x0, x1, std::copy(0, 0, 0) ) - A copy to a copy into a range not having the capacity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For C-style arrays the 'iterator' returned is just a pointer to the element type.

So in your case the return value of `std::copy()` would be `unsigned char*`.